# 英語が残っている：レビュー担当者統計における編集者統計の文言

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

編集者統計で、推奨が受け入れられた件数と拒否された件数に関する文言が英語になっていました。

[image: レビュー担当者統計]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/48712464

翻訳はされていたのですが、未レビュー状態だったせいで適用されていなかったのかもしれません。

修正しましたのでサイト反映をお待ちください。

Comment: rev 2015.8.21.696で反映されていることを確認しました。